# GDP per IP or location

Tags: city, postal-code, gdp

Is it any public database, API where I could download GDP data per location, per city or IP address?

Comment: City level GDP data is not available in many countries. You could use nighttime lights as a proxy (see Henderson, J. Vernon, Adam Storeygard, and David N. Weil. 2012. "Measuring Economic Growth from Outer Space." American Economic Review, 102 (2): 994-1028)

Comment: What about payed tax?

Comment: City governments should report their tax revenues somewhere. However, tax revenues are not a suitable proxy for GDP. At least in many rich countries, local governments can alter tax rates to some extent. Some cities e.g. lower taxes to attract firms. In poor countries there is another issue. They tend to have a large informal sector that does not pay direct taxes and varies in size across cities.